# Using String addingPercentEncoding to encode a string as query param

Tags: swift

I have an input string "+20" and I am trying to pass that as query parameter in url.

So I am trying to encode the myInputString by doing

```
let s1 = myInputString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

But in the debugger, the string s1 still shows as '+20' instead of '%2B20'

Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: `+` is a legal URL character. It doesn’t need encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by matt `+` is a legal URL character. If you really need to encode it you would need to create your own custom `urlQueryAllowed` and subtract the plus sign from it:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    static let allowedCharacters = urlQueryAllowed.subtracting(.init(charactersIn: "+"))
}
```

---

```
let myInputString = "+20"
let s1 = myInputString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .allowedCharacters)  // "%2B20"
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please help me understand why '+' is a valid character? When I go to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP, enter `1+20` and then 'Url encoded', I get `1%2B20`

Comment: `+` in an `URL` also  means a space.